# Saving User Output to a Text file

Tags: javascript, html

I am wanting to save user input to a text file that will be stored in my local folder directory with filename as date-time(hh-mm-ss).txt So once the user clicks the "save: button, it'll save the contents to that date-time(hh-mm-ss).txt file

*I am learning, so please show me with a little explanation, thank you*

Current html:

```
<form>
  Subject:
  <input type="text" id="subject" size="20">
  <br>

  Description:
  <textarea id="newDescription" rows="4" cols="50" required spellcheck="true"></textarea>
  <br>

  Tags:
  <input type="text" id="tags" size="20">
  <br>

  <input type="button" value="Save"
    onclick="addDescription(this.form);">
</form>
```

Current external JS:
// This function accepts user input.

```
  function addDescription(form) {
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = 
      form.elements["subject"].value + "<br>" +
      form.elements["newDescription"].value + "<br>" +
      form.elements["tags"].value + ".";
    form.reset();
    form.elements["subject"].value 
    form.elements["newDescription"].value 
    form.elements["tags"].value;
  } // end addDescription
```

**Also, if anyone has a better idea on how to make the appearance of the  portion of the html look better on the webpage because as of now the label and text boxes look crushed together!**

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript on the client side (in the browser) can't read or write files (imagine how dangerous that would be?).

To write a file you'd need server side technology such as NodeJS (if you want to stick with JS). The client side will need to send the data to your backend (NodeJS).

Instead of giving you copy & paste code, I'll give you direction on how to approach the problem, and resources that will get you there:

- Set up a backend with NodeJS. Easiest is to use Express:
  https://expressjs.com/
- To write files with your backend you can use plain NodeJS. Learn
  how to do that [here](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/file-system/how-to-write-files-in-nodejs/).
- Build your form correctly by learning from boilerplate code. A good
  framework for building out neat HTML and CSS might be [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/),
  or [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/).
- Post the user's data to your NodeJS backend from your form using the
  [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).